# To find Next element data-id of list in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get the data-id of next list element from the current active list element on button click?

```
 <div class="nbrs">
    <ul>
      <li id="item1" data-id="1" class="active">Coffee (first li)</li>
      <li id="item2" data-id="2">Tea (second li)</li>
      <li id="item3" data-id="3">Green Tea (third li)</li>
    </ul>
    </div>

   <button id="btnNext" type="button">Next</button>
```

The next element data-id need to be shown till the last (third) li.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find next `li` with `.next('li')` and find its attribute `data-id` value with `.attr('data-id')`. Remove `active` class from currently active li with `$('li.active').removeClass('active');` & add active class in next li with `next.addClass('active');`.

Try like below.

```js
$('#btnNext').click(function() {
  // find next li from currently active li
  let next = $('li.active').next('li');
  if (next.length > 0) {
    // remove active class from currently active li
    $('li.active').removeClass('active');
    // add active class in next li
    next.addClass('active');
    // get data id from next li
    let dataId = next.attr('data-id');
    alert(dataId);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nbrs">
  <ul>
    <li id="item1" data-id="1" class="active">Coffee (first li)</li>
    <li id="item2" data-id="2">Tea (second li)</li>
    <li id="item3" data-id="3">Green Tea (third li)</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button id="btnNext" type="button">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can make use of `next()` to get next li element and read data-id using `.data('id)`... see below code sample

```js
$(function(){
  $('#btnNext').on('click', function(){
     var $next = $('ul li.active').next('li');
     if($next.length > 0) {
      var id = $next.data('id');
      alert(id);
     }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nbrs">
  <ul>
    <li id="item1" data-id="1" class="active">Coffee (first li)</li>
    <li id="item2" data-id="2">Tea (second li)</li>
    <li id="item3" data-id="3" >Tea (third li)</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button id="btnNext" type="button">Next</button>
```

Comment: Your `if($next)` condition will always `true` because `next('li')` will always return object which has `length = 0`. You should use `if($next.length)`.

Answer (score 1):

Using vanilla Javascript, you can use the `.nextElementSibling()` on the li element that has a class of `active`. Wrap this in a loop that iterates to check the elements length with an iterator. Place a conditional that stops the iteration once we get to the length of the nodeList within an eventlistener on click of the button.

```js
const active = document.querySelectorAll('li');
const btn = document.getElementById('btnNext');

//--> initialize a counter
let i = 0;
//--> loop over the list item elements
active.forEach((val) => {
  //--> use the current element being looped over 
  //--> and check to see if it contains class of active 
  if (val.classList.contains('active')) {
    //--> event listener for the click of the button
    btnNext.addEventListener('click', () => {
      //--> here we add a constraint for the loop using .length against the counter
      //--> if our counter is less than the list items length minus 1
      //--> this means we have not reached the end of the list items
      if (i < active.length - 1) {             
        //--> we use the counter i as a key on the list items element list
        //--> to get the dataset.id of the nextElementSibling
        console.log(active[i].nextElementSibling.dataset.id);
        //--> increase counter by one for the next loop through logic
        i++;
      }
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="nbrs">
  <ul>
    <li id="item1" data-id="1" class="active anotherclass">Coffee (first li)</li>
    <li id="item2" data-id="2">Tea (second li)</li>
    <li id="item3" data-id="3">Green Tea (third li)</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button id="btnNext" type="button">Next</button>
```

Comment: Your condition `val.classList == 'active'` will not work if `td` has another class as well. like `class="active col"`. You should be using `val.classList.contains("active")`.

Comment: @Karan, I changed the code to accommodate multiple classes within the class attribute, it works now.